# Symfony not redirecting to login in AccessDeniedException

Tags: symfony-3.4, php-7.2

In my Symfony project (3.4) in AccessDenied Exception, it does not redirect to login path. Normally in Symfony projects if the user is not authenticated, it redirects to the login url. Is there anything which is needed to do in configuration?

Below is my security.yml

```
security:
    access_denied_url: /oauth/v2/auth/login
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

        Walkingspree\APIAuthBundle\Security\WebserviceUser:
            algorithm: md5
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        oauth_token:
            pattern:  ^/oauth/v2/token
            security: false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:   ^/oauth/v2/auth
            anonymous: true
            stateless: false
            #form_login:
            #    provider: walkingspree_members
            #    login_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login
            #    check_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login/check
            logout:
                path:   /oauth/logout
                target: /

        register:
            pattern:  ^/service/register
            security: false

        resetpw:
            pattern:  ^/service/account/password/reset
            security: false

        site:
            pattern:   ^/service/
            fos_oauth: true
            stateless: true
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_USER }        #form_login: ~
#        { path: ^/auth/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Thank you.

```
[2018-10-11 12:52:55] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_oauth_server_authorize". {"route":"fos_oauth_server_authorize","route_parameters":{"_controller":"fos_oauth_server.controller.authorize:authorizeAction","_route":"fos_oauth_server_authorize"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=3_5m8giw18bkowccck8k0s8gwooockscgskkkwscsgcgsosogog0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.walkingspree.com%2FNaS&response_type=code","method":"GET"} []
[2018-10-11 12:52:55] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []

[2018-10-11 12:52:55] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller_arguments" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\IsGrantedListener::onKernelControllerArguments". {"event":"kernel.controller_arguments","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\IsGrantedListener::onKernelControllerArguments"} []
[2018-10-11 12:52:55] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): This user does not have access to this section. at /srv/com.walkingspree.api/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/Controller/AuthorizeController.php:157)"} []
[2018-10-11 12:52:55] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InsufficientAuthenticationException: "Full authentication is required to access this resource." at /srv/com.walkingspree.api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php line 126 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\InsufficientAuthenticationException(code: 0): Full authentication is required to access this resource. at /srv/com.walkingspree.api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php:126, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): This user does not have access to this section. at /srv/com.walkingspree.api/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/Controller/AuthorizeController.php:157)"} []
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a 401 rather than a 403?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a part of the prod.log